# У кого то есть пример интеграции сайта с CRM через API, от а до я?

Tags: php, api

У кого то есть пример интеграции сайта с CRM через API, от а до я?
Нужно подвязать формы на сайте к CRM
У CRM есть открытые API https://yclients.docs.apiary.io/#
Но опыта работы с API у меня нет(
Но очень хочется научится. Гуглил но толком ничего не нашел.
Если у кого то есть пример который работает по такому же типу, поделитесь)

Comment: Stackoverflow - это не форум. Пишите конкретные вопросы, а не общие. В чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для меня оказалось более менее понятным это видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUxr61zDtzA